# Trying to get AI to recall set name in text file correctly

Tags: python

Literally, everything works. I am just trying to keep the brackets from showing up when she reads the line for the username.  I have tried a lot of things myself and nothing seems to work. Can anyone help?
My issue is on the readline in the except block

```
try:
    mem_recall=open('ai_memory.txt', 'x')
    mem_recall.close()
    print('Hi there. My name is Alice. What\'s yours?')
    u_name=input('Enter your name: ')
    mem_recall=open('ai_memory.txt', 'w')
    mem_recall.write('Username: '+str(u_name))
    mem_recall.close()
    mem_recall=open('ai_memory.txt', 'r')
    u_name=mem_recall.readlines(1)
    mem_recall.close()
    u_name=str(u_name).replace('Username: ', '')
    input('Welcome, '+str(u_name)+'.')
except:
    mem_recall=open('ai_memory.txt', 'r')
    u_name=mem_recall.readlines(1)
    mem_recall.close()
    u_name=str(u_name).replace('Username: ', '')
    print('Welcome back, '+str(u_name)+'.')
    sleep(0.5)
    print('Today is '  + str(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.date.today()), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m.%d.%Y')) + '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines):

```
u_name=mem_recall.readlines(1)
```

This returns a list of lines.

You then explicitly ask for the string representation of that list:

```
u_name=str(u_name).replace('Username: ', '')
```

The string representation of a list looks like this:

```
['this is the actual line here, inside quotes and brackets']
```

If you don't want that, just don't do that. If you just want one line, call [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline), not `readlines`:

```
u_name = mem_recall.readline()
u_name = u_name.replace('Username: ', '')
```